# CueBanner on wince

Tags: c#, windows-ce, dllimport, c#-2.0

I'm using a class that send a message using

```
EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;
```

and works fine on my desktop applications..

now I wish make the same on wince:
i've changed the dllimport from user32.dll to coredll.dll, the program doesn't crash, but the cuebanner is not shown...

is someone that can help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb01s86y.aspx) it's available for Windows XP and later. [This page](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/TextBox-Prompt.aspx) also suggests that it's not available for Windows CE.

Comment: thanks Stijn... I would read another type of answer, but is ok! have a nice day!